# MySQL / MariaDB column value unique in different column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a database schema for user login data that stores an E-Mail address for each user. Naturally, this E-Mail needs to be unique because each user should only have one account. I also have another column that stores a new, temporary E-Mail address if the user wants to change their E-Mail (upon changing it, the new address will temporarily be stored in this column and when the user accepts the change in an E-Mail that is send to them the change will actually occur).

My current setup is missing a way to check whether an E-Mail that should be stored in the temporary column is already stored in the non-temporary column.

Is there a way to do this, preferably using CHECK constraints?

I am using MariaDB version 15.

Comment: AFAIK you'd have to do that as a validation step in your application code or a stored procedure

Comment: which mariadb version : 15 is no version

Comment: mysql --version outputs this: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.14-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1 - 
I thought Ver 15.1 was the version.

Comment: However, based on @ADyson's answer, I solved the problem using a BEFORE UPDATE and INSERT trigger and manually raising an error. I am far from being an expert in databases, but my solution works fine so far.

Comment: It would be great if you posted your solution here as an Answer in case it helps others with a similar situation. You are allowed, in fact encouraged, to answer your own question if you can. Then others can vote it up if they found it useful

Answer (score 2):

The solution that I ended up with uses BEFORE UPDATE and BEFORE INSERT TRIGGERS:
"email" is the column for the main E-Mail and "new_email" is the column for the temporary address.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGG_prevent_duplicate_emails_update1
BEFORE UPDATE ON `DefaultLogins`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.new_email IN (SELECT `email` FROM `DefaultLogins`) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The new value for "new_email" already exists in "email".';
        END IF;
    END; //
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGG_prevent_duplicate_emails_insert1
BEFORE INSERT ON `DefaultLogins`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.new_email IN (SELECT `email` FROM `DefaultLogins`) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The new value for new_email already exists in "email".';
        END IF;
    END; //
DELIMITER ;
```